# Anticommutativity wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I have a problem with the underlined step of the demonstration (picture below) . Why can $f$ and $g$ be switched ? I can't seem to grasp this part, since I know tensor product is not, in general, commutative. It has to do with the permutation somehow. Someone care to explain?

[Anticommutativity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UHHm.jpg)

Comment: You are not commuting $f\wedge g$, but rather $f$ evaluated at $(v_{\sigma(1)},...,v_{\sigma(k)})$ with $g$ evaluated at $(v_{\sigma(k+1)},...,v_{\sigma(k+l)})$. These are elements of the field $\mathbb K$ and thus commute.

Comment: As @s.harp said, they are just numbers.